# Concatenated Field Join in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, relationship

I am trying to merge three tables into a single report and unfortunately do not have a unique key.  As a result, I need to concatenate 3 fields together into one unique key.  However since I am using a calculated field type, Access will not let me create a relationship between the tables.  Additionally when I update the tables with new data, I am losing my calculated column.

How can I create / use a unique key using concatenated strings? 
How do I ensure that I don't lose the calculated column when I import new data?

Comment: Why is that important for you whether you have a nominated unique key or not? It doesn't change your data. I think you don't need to concatenate the three fields, you can join on multiple fields in access. If you really want to concatenate them, than do it in a new query to where you select ask the data, this way you always will have them. (` SELECT *, field1 & field2 & field3 AS key FROM original_table`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than concatenating 3 fields together and joining on that single concatenated field you can just join on multiple fields.

[image: Query.png]

That can work for creating Relationships too:

[image: Relationships.png]

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks for the info, did not realize Access could handle queries like that.